# Selecting rows from a subset column

Tags: r

I have two datasets, where I need to find the matching names for 2 columns(name, publisher name).

The first thing I did was merge the two columns containing the name and publisher name into 1 column by inserting "and" before the names of the publishers. I then used the `intersect` function to find the matches between the two data sets. Then, I split the intersected data frame into 2 columns.

```
GooglePlay <- read.csv("...\\GooglePlay.csv", header = TRUE)
iTunes <- read.csv("...\\iTunes.csv", header = TRUE)

GooglePlay$gp_publisher_name1 <- sub("^", "and ", GooglePlay$gp_publisher_name)
iTunes$ios_publisher_name1 <- sub("^", "and ", iTunes$ios_publisher_name)
GoogleMerge <- paste(GooglePlay$gp_name, GooglePlay$gp_publisher_name1)
iTunesMerge <- paste(iTunes$ios_name, iTunes$ios_publisher_name1)
data.intersect <- intersect(GoogleMerge, iTunesMerge)
Matched.Cols <- str_split_fixed(data.intersect, "and", 2)
```

The Matched.Cols data set is a subset of both the GooglePlay and iTunes data sets, since it contains the common names of the apps and publishers. Now, I want to subset the GooglePlay and iTunes data sets to include **ALL ROWS THAT CONTAIN WHAT IS IN THE SUBSET THAT I CREATED**. I attempted this by using the `subset` function and the indices, but I kept getting either errors or a data frame full of NAS. It would be way too time consuming for me to subset the data sets by selecting the rows one by one.

```
dim(Matched.Cols)
[1] 12622     2
```

The subsets should have 12622 rows containing all the original variables but using the matched names of the apps and publishers.

Comment: Why not just put the relevant columns in the dataframes and do `merge(GooglePlay, iTunes)`?

Comment: @dash2 I did that but, it merged some columns when it shouldn't have. Perhaps I should rename them before merging?

Comment: or just use the `by` argument to specify which columns you want to merge by.

Comment: @dash2 @dash2 here's a simpler example. Say I have a matrix `V`, defined as `V <- matrix(1:28,nrow = 4,ncol = 7)`, and a matrix `W` defined as `W = matrix(c(100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,86,85,84,83,17,19,82,81,21,23,25,26,27,28),nrow = 4, ncol = 7)`. I want to find the intersected terms in the 5th and 6th columns of the matricies. They are (17,21) and (19,23). Now, I want to limit the matrix to the rows strictly containing those values in the 5th and 6th columns. Let's assume that I don't know which rows (17,21) and (19,23) are in.

Comment: Right, so by "intersected terms" you mean "rows where the 5th and 6th columns are the same". So, to repeat, why not just merge by these two columns? `V <- as.data.frame(V);W <- as.data.frame(W); merge(V, W , by = c('V5', 'V6'))`

Comment: @dash2, ohhh now it makes sense. thanks you very much. I applied those same functions to the GooglePlay and iTunes datasets and it got what I wanted.

Comment: No problem. I expect you know you can get help on a function by doing `?merge`.